# Парсинг сайта habr библиотекой bs

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Необходимо парсить страницу со свежими статьями (вот эту) и выбирать те статьи, в которых встречается хотя бы одно из ключевых слов (эти слова определяем в начале скрипта). Поиск вести по всей доступной preview-информации (это информация, доступная непосредственно с текущей страницы). Вывести в консоль список подходящих статей в формате: <дата> - <заголовок> - <ссылка>.

Вот мой код, но он не работает. Возможно ошибка в строчках
previews = article.find_all('div', class_='tm-article-snippet')
previews = set(preview.find('p', class_='article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-1').text for preview in previews)

```
import requests
import bs4

HEADERS = {
    'Cookies': 'yandexuid=7872100861644332491; yuidss=7872100861644332491; my=YwA=; ymex=1972109901.yrts.1656749901;'
               ' yandex_gid=117428; gdpr=0; _ym_uid=1645464466702207110; amcuid=4972560311656757599;'
               ' is_gdpr=1; is_gdpr_b=CNzDcxCdfBgBKAI=; _ym_d=1657306071;',
    'Acceept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                  ' Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0'}
# определяем список ключевых слов
KEYWORDS = {'дизайн', 'фото', 'web', 'Python', 'python'}

base_url = 'https://habr.com'
url = base_url + '/ru/all/'
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
text = response.text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, features='html.parser')
articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='tm-articles-list__item')
#print(articles)

for article in articles:
    previews = article.find_all('div', class_='tm-article-snippet')
    previews = set(preview.find('p', class_='article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-1').text for preview in previews)
    date = article.find('time').text
    title = article.find('a', class_='tm-article-snippet__title-link')
    span_title = title.find('span').text
    print(span_title)
    print(date)
    print(previews)

    if KEYWORDS & previews:
        href = title['href']
        result = f'Название татьи => {span_title} / Дата статьи {date} / Ссылка {base_url + href}'
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4
import requests

HEADERS = {
    'Cookies': 'yandexuid=7872100861644332491; yuidss=7872100861644332491; my=YwA=; ymex=1972109901.yrts.1656749901;'
               ' yandex_gid=117428; gdpr=0; _ym_uid=1645464466702207110; amcuid=4972560311656757599;'
               ' is_gdpr=1; is_gdpr_b=CNzDcxCdfBgBKAI=; _ym_d=1657306071;',
    'Acceept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                  ' Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0'}
# определяем список ключевых слов
KEYWORDS = {'дизайн', 'фото', 'web', 'Python', 'python'}

base_url = 'https://habr.com'
url = base_url + '/ru/all/'
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
text = response.text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, features='html.parser')
articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='tm-articles-list__item')

for article in articles:
    previews = [x.span.text for x in article.find_all('span', class_="tm-article-snippet__hubs-item")]
    date = article.time.text
    title = article.find('a', class_='tm-article-snippet__title-link')
    href = title['href']
    span_title = title.text
    # print(span_title)
    # print(date)
    # print(previews)

    for x in previews:
        if x in KEYWORDS:
            result = f'Название татьи => {span_title} / Дата статьи {date} / Ссылка {base_url + href}'
            print(result)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
previews = dict()
k = 0
for i in articles:
    preview = i.find(class_="article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-1")
    if preview:
        previews.setdefault(k, preview.text)
    else:
        preview = i.find(class_="article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-2")
        previews.setdefault(k, preview.text)
    k += 1
```

Решено через словарь, но можно списком. В любом случае превью зашито в класс article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-2 / article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-1.

В предыдущем ответе использован класс для поиска по хабам (по сути, тэгам), так что не совсем корректное решение.